# data, a data, game data, or your data for game localization?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I'm learning English and localizing some sentences for a game.
I have done it just in case but I'm not sure I should use "data", "game data", "a data", or "your game data", etc...
How can I write them?

(It will be used for the page to restore and save game data)

> **Data Restore**
>   If you have unsaved data of the game in progress, it will be updated.
>   Are you sure?
>
> **Data Transfer**
>   If you save your game data you can continue playing by restoring game data when you reinstall the game or getting a new phone.
>
> **Save Data**
>   You can save 1 data. If you have already saved data before, it will be updated.
>   Are you sure?

Comment: I don’t know exactly why you got a down vote but here are some tips. Please choose one sentence and ask about that. Otherwise this might be closed as “too broad”. Also, include your research and understanding of the problem, like what you think and why. Otherwise this might be closed as “answerable with a dictionary” or “lacking details”. There mght be other issues I can’t think of ATM. See the [help/on-topic] to see what’s on-topic and the [Contributor’s Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785) for tips and examples.

Comment: You can use "account" too. Example: Save/Restore/Recover account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly don't use "a data" at all because data is a plural noun.

Reconsider if "Data Restore" and "Data Transfer" are different operations - they appear to be the same operation performed for different reasons.

"Update" in English usually means to partially change something. If all of the data is replaced you can use verbs like "overwritten" or "replaced".

You can use "game" to mean "game data". Most readers are not looking for a technical explanation.

For thinking about, perhaps you could translate the instructions as:

> **Save game**
>
> Save the game in progress. Saving will overwrite any previously saved game.
>
> **Restore game**
>
> Restore a saved game. Restoration will replace any game in progress.